# Can anyone help me analyze these Huffman frequency scatter plots?

Tags: java, matlab, analysis, scatter-plot, huffman-code

I wrote a program implementing Huffman coding and I tested it out on 3 different types of files and then plotted their frequencies on a scatter plot in Matlab. The 3 different types of files are

1. **Text File(.txt):** I was able to reduce the file size from `65 KB` to `37 KB` i.e., almost like 43% compression.
2. **Audio File(.mp3):** I was able to reduce the file size from `99 KB` to `98 KB` i.e., almost like 1% compression (LOL).
3. **Compressed File(.rar):** I was able to reduce the file size from `16.1 KB` to `16.2 KB` i.e., almost like -1% compression(Big LOL).

Now I took the frequency of characters that occurred in each file before compression and made a scatter plot in Matlab. For example in this text: `mimmi`, m appears 3 times, and i appears 2 times, so I plotted the numbers 2 and 3 on x - axis and their corresponding y - values were simply some random numbers(they are not our concern). So here are the plots of these three files, so how to tell from these plots that a certain plot experienced good compression and a certain plot experienced bad compression? I am expecting that the answer is somewhere along the lines of how close these points are together or how far, so I need your help.

Plots are given down below. X - Axis includes the frequencies of the characters that occur in the file whereas the Y - Axis is something that we are not concerned. I mapped Y so that each point is plotted separately instead of one above the other(which would defeat the purpose of our analysis).

Note: My Huffman program fails miserably for files other than text files, I already asked an answer on SO and it seems that other types of files are already compressed(just like what happened with my 3rd case of compression with rar file where I got a -1% compression).

P.S I am not sure if I was able to explain my question clearly, but will edit it again if anyone asks me to.

[image: Text File]
[image: Audio]
[image: Rar File]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to estimate the compression from the frequencies, you can simply compute the entropy.

Sum the frequencies of the byte values times the logarithm base 2 of the frequencies (for those frequencies that are not zero). Then subtract that sum from the length of the input times the logarithm base 2 of the length. If the length is zero, then the entropy is zero.

That will give you the entropy in bits. You can divide by eight to get an approximation of the number of bytes in the Huffman-compressed result.